# Change the color of the node when it is clicked on in Pyvis

Tags: python, networkx, pyvis

I'm creating a network visualization in python using Pyvis. I know Pyvis is just a Java interpreter but still I'm not very familiar with Java so I'm trying to get as much as I can done with Python. I can create the graph as I want with no problem, but when I output the html file I want the nodes to change colors when I click on them. I've tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work. The data I'm using has the following structure but with a lot more nodes than this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyvis.network import Network

data = [['A','B', 1], ['A','C', 4], ['B','A', 1], 
        ['D','E', 5], ['D','F', 1], ['G','J', 7],
        ['A','J', 4], ['G','F', 14], ['C','L', 4], 
        ['A','F', 2], ['E','H', 12], ['I','E', 2],
        ['I','K', 4], ['L','H', 21]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['source', 'target', 'feature_count']

# Step 1: Initialize Network
graph = Network(height='750px', width='100%', directed=True)

# Step 2: Get sources, targets and weights
sources = df['source']
targets = df['targets']
weights = df['feature_count']

edge_data = zip(sources, targets, weights)

# Step 3: Create the graph adding each node individually.
for edge in edge_data:  
    source_name = edge[0]
    target_name = edge[1]
    weight = edge[2]

    graph.add_node(n_id=source_name, label=source_name, labelHighlightBold=True)
    graph.add_node(n_id=target_name, label=target_name, labelHighlightBold=True)
    graph.add_edge(source_name, target_name, value=weight, title=weight, arrowStrikethrough=False)

# Step 4: Use the options (Java) to specify that I want the color of the note to change to red when clicked on
options = {
    "configure": {
         "enabled": True
     },
    "interaction": {
        "hover": True
    },
    "nodes": {
         "borderWidth": 2,
         "borderWidthSelected": 4,
         "chosen" : True,
         "color": { "highlight": { "border": "#FF4040",
                                   "background": "#EE3B3B"
                     },
                    "hover": { "border": "#DEB887",
                               "background": "#FFD39B"
                     }
         }
     }
}

# Step 5: Define the options
graph.options = options


# Step 6: Visualize the Network
graph.show('graph.html')
```

So this code generates the network graph perfectly, but still the color of the nodes don't change when I click on them. Here is a picture of the html file that results from this:

[image]

And the weirdest thing is that even the buttons of the html file don't work neither for changing the colors, BUT THEY DO WORK FOR CHANGING ANYTHING ELSE LIKE THE FONT SIZE OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT.

I'd really appreciate the help.

Thanks!